# How to effectively google images without visiting Google Images?

Tags: google-search, google-image-search, keyword

Say I go to google.com and type in `thingtofind X`. What should `X` be so that the result is equivalently searching `thingtofind` in images.google.com?

The reason I'm asking this is because sometimes I want to search for image in the search bar of Firefox.

I try replacing X with [`picture of`](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=picture+of+obstreperous&oq=picture+of+obstreperous&gs_l=serp.3...12292.15079.0.15162.12.11.0.0.0.0.176.1137.0j8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..4.4.578.yoch8ho86q4)and [`image`](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=image+obstreperous&oq=image+obstreperous&gs_l=serp.3...98937.99519.0.100032.5.5.0.0.0.0.169.431.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.1.148...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.vjslZX_3_KE) but they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Start by going to [images.google.com](http://images.google.com) instead of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

ref:   https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/112511?hl=en

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is because sometimes I want to search for image in the search bar of Firefox

Comment: There is NO keyword at the current time:   In the search bar of firefox, you need to type  www.images.google.com - and then when you get to the images search page you can type your actual keywords.    (I agree there should be a keyword - but there not one today, according to Google's help)

Comment: If your browser supports custom search engines, this could work with Google Images.

Answer (score 1):

Search something like "[pizza type:image](https://www.google.com/search?q=pizza%20type:image&safe=strict&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1280&bih=739&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH0u3AmqzLAhVIkYMKHQKPBRwQ_AUIBigA&dpr=1#q=pizza%20type:image&safe=strict&tbs=li:1&start=0)". Not only will it give you images, it will also give you it as a file uploaded to wikis.

You also need verbatim enabled.

Comment: Even when I enable the verbatim feature, the result only provides me about 10 images, not a page of all images searched.

Comment: +Ooker the links are images to (not including ads)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Which links are you mentioning at?

Comment: +Ooker Sorry, forgot to finish the thing. I meant to put "wiki images".